# Read changes directly from an XML object using Python (lxml)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, xml-parsing, lxml

I have an XML file. I *load it as an XML object like* `xmlDoc = etree.parse(filePath)`. Then I add some same-named nodes (tag is "object") using `append`. Then if I save this xmlDoc using `xmlDoc.write(savingPath)` and I open the saved file, everything is fine and I can see the new added nodes there.

However, *if I want to count the nodes before saving to a file, I get the number of nodes as **ZERO***. I count like this `objectNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object")` then `print len(objectNodes)`

So everytime I want to count, I have to save the xmlDoc first to a file, then load the file again to xmlDoc and count the nodes.

***Why can't I count directly? What am I missing?***

**Update:** ***Here is an example with output results***

```
objectNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object")
print len(objectNodes)
xmlDoc.write(file, pretty_print=True)
xmlDoc= etree.parse(file)
objectNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object)
print len(objectNodes)
```

***Output:***

```
0
5
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not shown how you create your initial `ElementTree`. The one created this way works:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from lxml import etree

fname = 'b.xml'

objects = etree.Element("objects")
xmlDoc = etree.ElementTree(objects)
objects.append(etree.Element("object"))
objects.append(etree.Element("object"))
objects.append(etree.Element("object"))
objects.append(etree.Element("object"))
objectNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object")
print len(objectNodes)

xmlDoc.write(fname, pretty_print=True)
xmlDoc= etree.parse(fname)
objectNodes = xmlDoc.xpath("//object")
print len(objectNodes)
```

Output:

```
4
4
```